# send input value via ajax without using val() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input

my use-case is this : 
I have several `input` :

```
  <label class="minilabel">Field1</label><input type="text">
  ...
  <label class="minilabel">FieldN </label><input type="text">
```

I have to get the `value` of each `input` and then send it via `AJAX` (a `post` request). 
Usually I set an `ID` to each `input` then I retrieve it through `$("#id1").val()` .. `$("#idN").val()` , but it such intricate. There is an alternative way to get these values?

Comment: The guys have posted some ways about serialize(), it can be a good way, but don't forget to  use jQuery.each() when you want another way.

Comment: That would just leave you replicating something that is already in jQuery though, as you would have to collate name and value attributes in a loop and do the escaping for the content you are sending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('form').serialize();
```

...is your friend. This turns all data in the form into a query string that you pass in as the data attribute.

I ideally would wrap elements in a form (unless these are dynamically created) as you can reference the "action" attribute when sending the AJAX POST request and the page also remains HTML4/5 compliant. Something like this:

```
var $form = $('form');
$.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    "url": $form.attr('action'),
    "data": $form.serialize(),
    "success": function (r) {

    }
});
```

On the other side of this you can also serialise a jQuery object of collected input elements with something as simple as this:

```
$(":input").serialize();
```

(Thanks to Dziamid for this info)

Comment: You can serialize elements by $('#container').find(":input").serialize();

Comment: I'm trying to use serialize() but when I fill the input fields , and the i console.log(); the $("form").serialize() it returns a blank line. Is it because I'm filling those fields dynamically?

Comment: That should definitely be working. Can you set up an example in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

on Server side

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_GET, $params);
```

$params  should then be an array

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with jQuery .each()
you could do something like this:

```
var value = '';
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
  // get input value
  value = $(this).val();    

  // do whatever you need with the value
  // save in array to send later to server for example
  // ...
});
```